# Python - Turn Thread into Multiprocessing

Tags: python, json, multithreading, multiprocessing, threadpool

So in those past days I have been trying to figure out how to even start getting at thread and I finally got it to work! The issue I am having now is that I want them to run simultaneously. I'm hearing different things such as GIL won't work. Some say it works with `multiprocessing` etc etc.. However I turned here to see if its possible and whats the say to do it?

Basically my code looks right now like this:

**The code with Thread**

```
def start(config):
    NameUrl = config["Url"]
    myNote = config["My-Note"]
    checkoutNames(Nameurl, MyNote)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('config.json', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as json_data:
        config = json.load(json_data)
    threads = []
    for i, e in enumerate(config):
        threads.append(threading.Thread(target=start, args=(config[i] or e)))
```

As you can see in `if __name__ == '__main__':` That's where the thread is at this moment. However what this does at this moment is that it first does thread 1, when its done it turns to thread 2 and goes on like that and my wish is to turn it into concurrently/simultaneously if that is even possible?

**EDIT**

*CODE*

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('config.json', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as json_data:
        config = json.load(json_data)
    jobs = []
    for i, e in enumerate(config):
        c = (config[i] or e)
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=start, args=(c))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

*The error iam getting with the code above:*

```
[<Process(Process-1, initial)>]
<Process(Process-1, initial)>
{'Email': '123o@gmail.com', 'PersonNumber': '4234', 'ZipCode': '1241234', 'Name': 'Guess', 'LastName': 'TheyKnow'}
[<Process(Process-1, started)>, <Process(Process-2, initial)>]
<Process(Process-2, initial)>
{'Email': 'Hello@hotmail.com', 'PersonNumber': '1234', 'ZipCode': '56431', 'Name': 'Stack', 'LastName': 'Overflow'}
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: start() takes 1 positional argument but 16 were given
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: start() takes 1 positional argument but 16 were given
```

Comment: Yes, Multiprocessing will work simultaneously as long as your CPU has the cores to handle it. Try using `import multiprocessing` and `multiprocessing.Process` and see if you can get it working.

Comment: If your actual work boils down to using `requests` (or equivalent) to fetch data, you should have no problems with the GIL. The GIL only affects CPU-intensive code that does actual calculations. What is the concrete problem you are solving?

Comment: @quamrana The only issue iam having now is to turn ```threads.append(threading.Thread(target=start, args=(config[i] or e)))``` into multiprocessing. Do you might have any idea? Is it just change threading.Thread into ```multiprocessing.Process```?

Comment: @user4815162342 Basically we say I have 10 objects (Json). What I just want to do is that to run all those profiles into multiprocessing and execute the code at the same time => Instead of waiting 1 after 1 to actually run them all at the same time. Thats pretty much it

Comment: Yes I do. See first comment.

Comment: Yes I just did it. Seems to still be going 1 and 1. I tried to add a start aswell but it just gives me ```TypeError: start() takes 1 positional argument but 16 were given``` I have edited the thread and you can probably see now what I have done

Comment: Dang it. I removed the p.start which says its a self.run. It does work but still goes one and one.. Is it wrong on the for loop maybe?

Comment: I'm not sure how a `Thread` or `Process` can even run if `start()` is not called on it. Are you sure you don't have `config` being processed linearly elsewhere?

Comment: @WeInThis What does the code you are executing **do**? If it is not a calculation, you should be just fine with threads.

Comment: You must post in the question the actual code you are running, otherwise everyone here gets very confused.

Comment: Can you please the shortest possible code that doesn't behave like you'd want it to? Otherwise this question is not really answerable.

Comment: @user4815162342 - The code is based on Request where I basically just train with get and post on simple website that my friend made so basically what I do is that I want to insert from the Json objects into his website to see if it is possible to do that with gets/posts. So now I have done it with using only ONE json object and what I want to do is that I want to make it possible so if I create 5 Json objects. Instead of waiting one and one to execute the same code. I want it to run all simultaneously so it will process it faster than 1 and 1.

Comment: @user4815162342 Also im gonna short the code now to make it more easier too see.

Comment: Note that the code you posted is minimal, but not complete and verifiable - you can't run it without access to `config` and `checkoutNames`. That no longer matters for this question, where someone managed to debug the problem for you anyway, but it might come in useful for future questions. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for details.

Comment: @user4815162342 It fine. The solution below was the correct one. I also don't want to post a whole code that can be a question for 3-4 other questions. Im just looking for one solution and it has been fixed :) Thank you too!

Comment: It's not about posting the whole code, it's about posting the minimal code *that still shows the problem*. I'm aware this question has been resolved, just pointing it out for future questions you might have. Have fun with StackOverflow! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to fix the args parameter:

```
...
jobs = []
for i, e in enumerate(config):
    c = (config[i] or e)
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=start, args=(c,))
    jobs.append(p)
    p.start()
```

Note the syntax used in the `args` parameter:

```
args=(c,))  # <=== (c,) means that we are assigning the tuple (c,) to args
            # which gets translated into start(c)
```

Comment: Well it did gave the same result. However the ```args=(c,))``` the comma gives me a error saying that it can not find ```NameError: name 'i' is not defined``` but when I remove the comma after *C* it gives me another error saying ```self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

TypeError: start() takes 1 positional argument but 16 were given```

But the program still runs anyways in the background even though the error... And also it is running 1 and 1 once again.

Comment: That's not possible. You must have some other code running somewhere.

Comment: I haev added the error into the thread now. Since its too long to post it here

Comment: And also if I add the "c," like you have. Then it will give me a error saying ```NameError: name 'i' is not defined```

Comment: That's not possible. You must have written some other code that you are not posting.